# Pool water heater wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring, heater, pool

I want to plug my water heater. I have a 240 #10 wire, plugged on a double 30AMP breaker. My wiring, cable and breaker are all OK. But when I opened the box on the heater, I found 5 plugs: L1, L2, Ground, 1, 2.

I think I must use the L1 and L2 ? (and ground of course) If my understanding is good, the 1 and 2 are OUT for my pump ?
If yes, must I absolutely use the OUT to the pump ? My pump is already pluggued in a outlet on another breaker and I prefer it that way, because we start using the pump in the spring before we install the heater that we store inside for the winter.

Here's a picture of the heater:
[image]

And a picture of the diagram in the manual:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit worried about something that says *eclectic* instead of *electric*. Just saying...

Comment: What make and model is this pool heater of yours?

Comment: The box is for a wide variety of circuitry, @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact. Nothing wrong with a varied collection of devices. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes L1 and L2 are there to power the heater. It must be protected by a GFCI.

The 1 and 2 lugs are there to control a contactor which switches the pump on and off. This contactor will let the heater control the pump while staying on a separate circuit.

To do that you take a contactor with 240 V control coil and contacts rated for the pump's amperage. Route the power to the pump through the contactor contacts and connect the 1 and 2 lugs to the control coil. You can put the contactor before the outlet of the pump and make that outlet dedicated to the pump. The breaker for the pump must also be a GFCI.

Comment: Thanks! But can I plug the pump separately without going through the heater ? Will the heater work without controlling the pump ?

Comment: You don't have to control the pump with the heater. It's supposed to be a safety to prevent the heater from running without the pump running. Some heaters also have a timer built in so you can let the heater take over timing the pool pump.

Comment: @StefFunaro speaking of safety, make sure you hook up ground!